# Setting background color of each character in textArea

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'am new to JavaFX. I want to do something like in the following image inside my TextArea. I think it can be done using the Label and set the background color of it. But how?

[image]

Comment: Not with a `TextArea`. Do you need it to be editable?

Comment: @James_D hi....Thanks for replying ....sorry i didn't get you ..I have String of characters and i want to display that String in above format inside my container i am using text area right now to hold the String ..... can we print string characters on label and put the series of labels inside container is it possible ......Waiting

Comment: I just meant that you couldn't do this with a `TextArea`, which is usually used for editing text. If you didn't need it editable, then you can use an `HBox` with `Label`s, as Uluk has shown to display your Arabidopsis Thaliana sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by putting the `Label` into some layout container, say `HBox`:

```
private final Random random = new Random();

private final Color[] colors =
{
    Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW
};


@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    String str = "my-string-val";
    for ( String s : str.split( "" ) )
    {
        Label l = new Label( s );
        l.setBorder( new Border( new BorderStroke( Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT ) ) );
        l.setBackground( new Background( new BackgroundFill( colors[random.nextInt( colors.length )], CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY ) ) );
        l.setPrefWidth( 20 );
        l.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
        l.setFont( font( "Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 16 ) );
        hbox.getChildren().add( l );
    }

    final Scene scene = new Scene( hbox, 800, 600 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();

}
```